# Dimenstions of Custom Layer Output Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Normally, keras layers have the output dimension with form `(None, c, h, w)`, or `(None, h, w, c)`, depending on `channels_first` or `channels_last` configuration.

I am trying to use custom keras layers, with two inputs. When I print the model summary, it does not show the `None` dimension.

How do I program my custom layer to include this None dimension?

I think this might be the cause of why i am receiving the error

```
No data provided for "crfrnn". Need data for each key in: ['crfrnn']
```

`crfrnn` is the name of my custom layer

I tried reshaping the output in the `call()` method, unluckily to no avail.

I made sure that the input data is shaped and prepared properly. Please note that my code was training fine before I tried adding this layer on top of the `plant_output` layer (see summary below)

Below is the code for the custom layer, it was adopted from [this github repository](https://github.com/sadeepj/crfasrnn_keras):

```
class CrfRnnLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """ Implements the CRF-RNN layer described in:

    Conditional Random Fields as Recurrent Neural Networks,
    S. Zheng, S. Jayasumana, B. Romera-Paredes, V. Vineet, Z. Su, D. Du, C. Huang and P. Torr,
    ICCV 2015
    """

    def __init__(self, image_dims, num_classes,
                 theta_alpha, theta_beta, theta_gamma,
                 num_iterations, NCHW, **kwargs):
        self.image_dims = image_dims
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.theta_alpha = theta_alpha
        self.theta_beta = theta_beta
        self.theta_gamma = theta_gamma
        self.num_iterations = num_iterations
        self.NCHW = NCHW
        self.spatial_ker_weights = None
        self.bilateral_ker_weights = None
        self.compatibility_matrix = None
        super(CrfRnnLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):

        if not self.NCHW:
            channel_axis = -1
            if input_shape[channel_axis] is None:
                raise ValueError('The channel dimension of the inputs '
                    'should be defined. Found `None`.')

            input_dim = input_shape[0][channel_axis]
            self.input_spec = [tf.keras.layers.InputSpec(shape=(None, input_shape[0][1], input_shape[0][2], input_shape[0][3])), tf.keras.layers.InputSpec(shape=(None, input_shape[1][1], input_shape[1][2], input_shape[1][3]))]

        else:
            channel_axis = 1
            if input_shape[channel_axis] is None:
                raise ValueError('The channel dimension of the inputs '
                    'should be defined. Found `None`.')

            input_dim = input_shape[0][channel_axis]
            self.input_spec = [tf.keras.layers.InputSpec(shape=(None, input_shape[0][1], input_shape[0][2], input_shape[0][3])), tf.keras.layers.InputSpec(shape=(None, input_shape[1][1], input_shape[1][2], input_shape[1][3]))]

        # Weights of the spatial kernel
        self.spatial_ker_weights = self.add_weight(name='spatial_ker_weights',
                                                   shape=(self.num_classes, self.num_classes),
                                                   initializer=_diagonal_initializer,
                                                   trainable=True)

        # Weights of the bilateral kernel
        self.bilateral_ker_weights = self.add_weight(name='bilateral_ker_weights',
                                                     shape=(self.num_classes, self.num_classes),
                                                     initializer=_diagonal_initializer,
                                                     trainable=True)

        # Compatibility matrix
        self.compatibility_matrix = self.add_weight(name='compatibility_matrix',
                                                    shape=(self.num_classes, self.num_classes),
                                                    initializer=_potts_model_initializer,
                                                    trainable=True)

        super(CrfRnnLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):

        unaries = tf.transpose(inputs[0][0, :, :, :], perm=(2, 0, 1))
        rgb = tf.transpose(inputs[1][0, :, :, :], perm=(2, 0, 1))

        #input is channels first
        c, h, w = self.num_classes, self.image_dims[0], self.image_dims[1]

        all_ones = np.ones((c, h, w), dtype=np.float32)

        # Prepare filter normalization coefficients
        spatial_norm_vals = custom_module.high_dim_filter(all_ones, rgb, bilateral=False,
                                                          theta_gamma=self.theta_gamma)
        bilateral_norm_vals = custom_module.high_dim_filter(all_ones, rgb, bilateral=True,
                                                            theta_alpha=self.theta_alpha,
                                                            theta_beta=self.theta_beta)
        q_values = unaries

        for i in range(self.num_iterations):
            softmax_out = tf.nn.softmax(q_values, 0)

            # Spatial filtering
            spatial_out = custom_module.high_dim_filter(softmax_out, rgb, bilateral=False,
                                                        theta_gamma=self.theta_gamma)
            spatial_out = spatial_out / spatial_norm_vals

            # Bilateral filtering
            bilateral_out = custom_module.high_dim_filter(softmax_out, rgb, bilateral=True,
                                                          theta_alpha=self.theta_alpha,
                                                          theta_beta=self.theta_beta)
            bilateral_out = bilateral_out / bilateral_norm_vals

            # Weighting filter outputs
            message_passing = (tf.matmul(self.spatial_ker_weights,
                                         tf.reshape(spatial_out, (c, -1))) +
                               tf.matmul(self.bilateral_ker_weights,
                                         tf.reshape(bilateral_out, (c, -1))))

            # Compatibility transform
            pairwise = tf.matmul(self.compatibility_matrix, message_passing)

            # Adding unary potentials
            pairwise = tf.reshape(pairwise, (c, h, w))
            q_values = unaries - pairwise

        #output is channels last
        return tf.transpose(tf.reshape(q_values, (1, c, h, w)), perm=(0, 2, 3, 1))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

This layer has two inputs, each with size `(None, 384, 512, 3)`. I expect the output to be the same, but when i compile the model, the summary produced is as follows (please note that I did not show alot of layers in the middle because i breached the character limit on this platform, the most important layers to see are `input_node`, `plant_output`, and custom `crfrnn`):

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_node (InputLayer)         (None, 384, 512, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_conv1 (Conv2D)          (None, 384, 512, 32) 128         input_node[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bneck1_dense_encoder1 (Conv2D)  (None, 384, 512, 8)  264         encoder_conv1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 384, 512, 8)  32          bneck1_dense_encoder1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu (LeakyReLU)         (None, 384, 512, 8)  0           batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_dense_encoder1 (Conv2D)   (None, 384, 512, 4)  292         leaky_re_lu[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 384, 512, 4)  0           conv1_dense_encoder1[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 384, 512, 36) 0           encoder_conv1[0][0]              
                                                                 dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bneck2_dense_encoder1 (Conv2D)  (None, 384, 512, 8)  296         concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 384, 512, 8)  32          bneck2_dense_encoder1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 384, 512, 8)  0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_dense_encoder1 (Conv2D)   (None, 384, 512, 4)  292         leaky_re_lu_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 384, 512, 4)  0           conv2_dense_encoder1[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 384, 512, 40) 0           concatenate[0][0]                
                                                                 dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bneck3_dense_encoder1 (Conv2D)  (None, 384, 512, 8)  328         concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 384, 512, 8)  32          bneck3_dense_encoder1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 384, 512, 8)  0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_dense_encoder1 (Conv2D)   (None, 384, 512, 4)  292         leaky_re_lu_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 384, 512, 4)  0           conv3_dense_encoder1[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 384, 512, 12) 0           dropout[0][0]                    
                                                                 dropout_1[0][0]                  
                                                                 dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_concat1 (Concatenate)   (None, 384, 512, 44) 0           encoder_conv1[0][0]              
                                                                 concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_bneck1 (Conv2D)         (None, 384, 512, 22) 990         encoder_concat1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_downsample1 (Conv2D)    (None, 192, 256, 22) 12122       encoder_bneck1[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bneck1_dense_encoder2 (Conv2D)  (None, 192, 256, 8)  184         encoder_downsample1[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 192, 256, 8)  32          bneck1_dense_encoder2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 192, 256, 8)  0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_dense_encoder2 (Conv2D)   (None, 192, 256, 4)  292         leaky_re_lu_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 192, 256, 4)  0           conv1_dense_encoder2[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 192, 256, 26) 0           encoder_downsample1[0][0]        
                                                                 dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bneck2_dense_encoder2 (Conv2D)  (None, 192, 256, 8)  216         concatenate_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 192, 256, 8)  32          bneck2_dense_encoder2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 192, 256, 8)  0           batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_dense_encoder2 (Conv2D)   (None, 192, 256, 4)  292         leaky_re_lu_4[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 192, 256, 4)  0           conv2_dense_encoder2[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_4 (Concatenate)     (None, 192, 256, 30) 0           concatenate_3[0][0]              
                                                                 dropout_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bneck3_dense_encoder2 (Conv2D)  (None, 192, 256, 8)  248         concatenate_4[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 192, 256, 8)  32          bneck3_dense_encoder2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_5 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 192, 256, 8)  0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_dense_encoder2 (Conv2D)   (None, 192, 256, 4)  292         leaky_re_lu_5[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 192, 256, 4)  0           conv3_dense_encoder2[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_5 (Concatenate)     (None, 192, 256, 12) 0           dropout_3[0][0]                  
                                                                 dropout_4[0][0]                  
                                                                 dropout_5[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_concat2 (Concatenate)   (None, 192, 256, 34) 0           encoder_downsample1[0][0]        
                                                                 concatenate_5[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_bneck2 (Conv2D)         (None, 192, 256, 17) 595         encoder_concat2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
encoder_downsample2 (Conv2D)    (None, 96, 128, 17)  7242        encoder_bneck2[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bneck1_dense_encoder3 (Conv2D)  (None, 96, 128, 8)   144         encoder_downsample2[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 96, 128, 8)   32          bneck1_dense_encoder3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_6 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 96, 128, 8)   0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv1_dense_encoder3 (Conv2D)   (None, 96, 128, 4)   292         leaky_re_lu_6[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)             (None, 96, 128, 4)   0           conv1_dense_encoder3[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_6 (Concatenate)     (None, 96, 128, 21)  0           encoder_downsample2[0][0]        
                                                                 dropout_6[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bneck2_dense_encoder3 (Conv2D)  (None, 96, 128, 8)   176         concatenate_6[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_7 (BatchNor (None, 96, 128, 8)   32          bneck2_dense_encoder3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_7 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 96, 128, 8)   0           batch_normalization_7[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2_dense_encoder3 (Conv2D)   (None, 96, 128, 4)   292         leaky_re_lu_7[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)             (None, 96, 128, 4)   0           conv2_dense_encoder3[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_7 (Concatenate)     (None, 96, 128, 25)  0           concatenate_6[0][0]              
                                                                 dropout_7[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bneck3_dense_encoder3 (Conv2D)  (None, 96, 128, 8)   208         concatenate_7[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_8 (BatchNor (None, 96, 128, 8)   32          bneck3_dense_encoder3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_8 (LeakyReLU)       (None, 96, 128, 8)   0           batch_normalization_8[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3_dense_encoder3 (Conv2D)   (None, 96, 128, 4)   292         leaky_re_lu_8[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)             (None, 96, 128, 4)   0           conv3_dense_encoder3[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_8 (Concatenate)     (None, 96, 128, 12)  0           dropout_6[0][0]                  
                                                                 dropout_7[0][0]                  
                                                                 dropout_8[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
plant_conv (Conv2D)             (None, 384, 512, 32) 416         concatenate_20[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
plant_output (Conv2D)           (None, 384, 512, 3)  99          plant_conv[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
crfrnn (CrfRnnLayer)            (1, 384, 512, 3)     27          plant_output[0][0]               
                                                                 input_node[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 41,833
Trainable params: 41,497
Non-trainable params: 336
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Notice how the crfrnn layer has shape (1, 384, 512, 3). I believe this is causing the program not to train, throwing the error:

```
Epoch 1/2000
No data provided for "crfrnn". Need data for each key in: ['crfrnn']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was two-fold, the first more important to share.

In the code above, in the call() function, you see:

```
unaries = tf.transpose(inputs[0][0, :, :, :], perm=(2, 0, 1))
rgb = tf.transpose(inputs[1][0, :, :, :], perm=(2, 0, 1))
```

I removed this and instead wrote:

```
unaries = inputs[0]    
rgb = inputs[1]
```

This assumes that the channels are being inputted as channels first, and therefore do not need to be transposed. Also, but reading them in like this, keras was able to infer shape and the summary now has (None, c, h, w) as the shape for this layer.

The error `No data provided for "crfrnn". Need data for each key in: ['crfrnn']` was actually a silly mistake on my part, where the label dictionary i was feeding had the wrong key (should have been crfrnn). I posted this on the original github for the crfrnn repo, because others were curious how to adopt this layer into their own networks, and i have done so.